# Why my image tag has an error as "unexpected token?

Tags: reactjs, image, token

I get an error as "`SyntaxError: C:\Users\Admin\image-search\src\App.js: Unexpected token, expected` "," " at my img tag line. Does anybody knows what is wrong?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import images from "./api-mock.json";

function App() {
  const [imageList, setImageList] = useState(images.resources);
  return (
    <div className="image-grid">
      {" "}
      {imageList.map((image) => (
        <img src={image.url} alt={image.public_id}/>
          {" "}
      ))}{" "}
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: try removing all those `{" "}` empty strings in JSX

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `{" "}` after `img`

```
return (
    <div className="image-grid">
      {" "}
      {imageList.map((image) => (
        <img src={image.url} alt={image.public_id} />
      ))}{" "}
    </div>
  );
```